# How to enable bmcweb in openbmc

Tags: linux, yocto, openbmc

Now I'm success to build the openbmc and run it on a server with aspeed2500 bmc.

I can login openbmc and also ssh on it.
But I can't access the webui by browser.

This site can't be reached
refused to connect.

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

How can i access webui by browser ?

Comment: https://lists.ozlabs.org/pipermail/openbmc/2018-December/014297.html

Answer (score 1):

First you should feel free to reach out on the discord https://discord.gg/69Km47zH98
Or on Email list, and ask the experts for more detailed help.

I will share what I do when I want to know if BMC web is working on a machine.

- Make sure the bitbake recipe is in included
- Make sure bmcweb is running, and there are not error message
- Make sure the network is allowing bmcweb to receive and send message

To make sure the recipe is included I typical run

`find -name bmcweb`
at the bitbake build directory. It should be in rootfs. If you don't see bmcweb in the build directory, there is a issue with your recipes, and it it is not being included.

To make sure bmcweb is running on the bmc, I ssh on and run `ps | grep "bmcweb`or `journalctl -u bmcweb` or `systemctl status bmcweb`
.Typically Typically these give me confidence bmcweb is running, or give indication it is not running.

The network is the most difficult item for me to check. The `netstat` command will indicate what ports are open on the bmc. Or from the host you can run `nmap ${bmc_ip}` to list open ports.

Those are the three steps I follow when I am unsure about bmcweb. Feel welcome to reach out to the discord or Email list.