# How to enable bmcweb in evb-ast2600 using openbmc?

Tags: linux, yocto, openbmc

I have a same problem with this : [How to enable bmcweb in openbmc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001188/how-to-enable-bmcweb-in-openbmc).
The only diff is that I want to use evb-ast2600. 
 I tried with openbmc's source (https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc) and aspeed's source(https://github.com/AspeedTech-BMC/openbmc), but both are failed in same way.

I can login BMC, but an't be reached refused to connect <ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED>.

This is the SAME way I tried.

```
git clone https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc
cd openbmc
source setup evb-ast2600
bitbake obmc-phosphor-image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I successed. I recommend clone https://github.com/AspeedTech-BMC/openbmc more than openbmc/openbmc. Just follow this.
`source setup ast2600-evb && bitbake obmc-phosphor-image` 
 And never forget, you must use 'https' rather than 'http'.